error: declaration of 'struct cs_target' will not be visible outside of this function [-Werror,-Wvisibility] when building kernel for android
I'm new to building kernels for android. And I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for several days now. Here's the error:
../kernel/cgroup/cpuset.c:1794:16: error: declaration of 'struct cs_target' will not be visible outside of this function [-Werror,-Wvisibility]
                                           struct cs_target tgt, size_t nbytes,
                                                  ^
../kernel/cgroup/cpuset.c:1794:26: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct cs_target'
                                           struct cs_target tgt, size_t nbytes,
                                                            ^
../kernel/cgroup/cpuset.c:1794:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct cs_target'
                                           struct cs_target tgt, size_t nbytes,

How can i solve this? Sources
Here are my steps:
cd /home/me/kuroneko_r_mt6765
export ARCH=arm64
export SUBARCH=arm
export CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
export CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=arm-linux-gnueabi-
make blossom_defconfig O=out
make -j4 CC=clang O=out

